# Why can any values of C and N be chosen for the proof of Big-Oh?

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

In my CS course, they have taught us that, when proving Big-Oh, you can choose any positive integers to be C and k, following the definition.

Based on that, they have taught us two different ways of proving a big-oh problem, for example:

Let $f(n) = 10n+5$, and $g(n) = n$. Prove that $f(n)$ is $O(g(n))$

**Method 1:**

Try C = 15

now show that $$10n+5 \leq 15n$$

$$2n + 1 \leq 3n$$
$$1 \leq n$$

so we can say k = 1 and thus n $\geq$ , hence $f(n)$ is $O(g(n))$ for C = 15 and k = 1.

**Method 2**

try k = 1

Assume $n \geq k$

Now show that $$(10n+5)/n \leq C$$

$$(10n+5n)/n \leq C$$
$$15n/n \leq C$$
$$C = 15$$

hence $f(n)$ is $O(g(n))$ for C = 15 and k = 1.

**My issues**

Is there a mathematical reason why we can choose C and k in these methods to be any number? Why does any value of C and k always work?

Why, in method 2, do we simply multiply 5 by n? How does this work? What is the reasoning behind this step?

Comment: I think it would be helpful to write the definition of $f(x) = O(g(x))$: that means we can find **some** constants $C$ and $k$ such that, for all $x > k$, we have $|f(x)| \leq C|g(x)|$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all comes down to what the definition of $f(n)=O(g(n))$.

**Definition** A non-negative function $f(n)$ is Big-Oh of $g(n)$, written $f(n)=O(g(n))$, if there exist constants $N$ and $C$ so that for all $n\geq N$ it follows that $f(n)\leq Cg(n)$.

The ability to choose $N$ and $C$ at will is because you only have to show that the inequality works for one choice.  If the inequality holds for all $n\geq N$ (the $N$ you chose with the $C$ you chose) then the definition is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

We can't choose any value of $C$ and $k$, we can only use values that work (and that's enough, we just need one pair to demonstrate the relationship!)

For example, if you want to show that $f(x) = x$ is $O(g(x))$ where $g(x) = x + 5$, you can't choose any $C \leq 1$; you'll never be able to find a $k$ such that

$$x \leq C(x + 5) = Cx + 5C$$ for all $x > k$; it's just not going to happen.

Nevertheless, to demonstrate that the relationship exists, we just need to demonstrate that *some* pair will work. And any values of $C$ and $k$ that *do* work are good enough for us.

Heuristically, we just want that "eventually" the function $f(x)$ is "approximately" at most as big as $g(x)$.

The "eventually" part is ensured by making the relationship hold for all $x > k$. At some point, we get to all the large enough $x$-values where the inequalities takes hold, and continues to hold.

The constant $C$ takes care of the "approximately" part. We're just happy if $f(x)$ can stay below some multiple of $g(x)$. You know, if we squint, $f(x)$ is "approximately" no bigger than $g(x)$.